# ReactJS - Reacting to a value that is outside of React-Tree. Alternative to Vue's ref() and reactivity()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about ReactJS. I was using VueJS for my game UI and I want to move on to ReactJS to build a UI in-game, but I want to keep logic decoupled from react tree to reduce performance issues. For example. I have my data/entities stored outside the ReactJS component.

- Let's say I have a loop where I update the value of class A every frame, now I want to display that value in ReactJS but Class A is not instantiated in React component.

Example of the following code

```
class Test {
  private health: number
  constructor() {
    this.health = 100
  }

  tick = () => {
    this.health -= 1
  }

  public getHealth = () => this.health 
}

const instance = new Test

// Somewhere in rAF ticker
...
   instance.tick()
...
```

Now i want in ReactJS react to the health change,

```
const Health = () => {
    const health = useRef(instance)
    
     // Use effect does not trigger on health changes 

    return <p> Health: {instance.health.current}</p>
}
export default Health
```

In VueJS there is a functionality where i can mark outside Vue component properties as `ref()` or `reactive` in case of objects. Is there similar functionality in ReactJS?

Why?

In my case, I will have a lot of entities and values that will change every frame and having all these things wrapped in components would be extremely costly, perhaps reactJS is not a good framework for me.

Comment: React built in state is very minimal.  But there are lots of different state managers out there,  Recoil is a nice an easy one to learn, as it's atomic's makes decoupled state much easier.  Redux used to be popular, but I find it too verbose.

Comment: @Keith Thanks! I did not think about Recoil, I will check it out and close this question if I get the desired result!

Answer (score 0):

With help of @Keith answer i used `Recoil` and `Recoil Nexus` to manage states with ReactJS and find desired solution!